# Scoring wont work in vb wfa

Tags: vb.net

im a total noob in programing but i really need help
anyway i have to do a 10 question program in school and it allways counts wrong like 5/10 when they are all corect but here is the code

Public Class Form1

```
Dim score As Integer = 0
Dim varname As String


Private Sub cmdsubmit_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cmdsubmit.Click
    varname = txtname.Text
    If txtbox1.Text = 18 Then
        score = score + 1
    End If
    If txtbox1.Text <= 18 Then
        score = score - 1
    End If
    If txtbox1.Text >= 18 Then
        score = score + 0
    End If
    If txtbox2.Text = 10 Then
        score = score + 1
    End If
    If txtbox2.Text <= 10 Then
        score = score + 0
    End If
    If txtbox2.Text >= 10 Then
        score = score + 0
    End If
    If rb11.Checked = True Then
        score = score + 1
    End If
    If rb2q3.Checked = True Then
        score = score + 0
    End If
    If cmboxq4.Text = "windows xp" Then
        score = score + 1
    End If
    If rbq5.Checked = True Then
        score = score + 1
    End If
    If score = 0 Then
        MsgBox("you have scored 0 out of 10" & varname)
    End If
    If score = 1 Then
        MsgBox("you have scored 1 out of 10 " & varname)
    End If
    If score = 2 Then
        MsgBox("you have scored 2 out of 10" & varname)
    End If
    If score = 3 Then
        MsgBox("you have scored 3 out of 10" & varname)
    End If
    If score = 4 Then
        MsgBox("you have scored 4 out of 10" & varname)
    End If
    If score = 5 Then
        MsgBox("you have scored 5 out of 10" & varname)
    End If
    If score = 6 Then
        MsgBox("you have scored 6 out of 10" & varname)
        If score = 7 Then
            MsgBox("you have scored 7 out of 10" & varname)
            If score = 8 Then
                MsgBox("you have scored 8 out of 10" & varname)
                If score = 9 Then
                    MsgBox("you have scored 9 out of 10" & varname)

                End If
            End If
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: You should put `Option Strict On` at the top of your code file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your comparisons (at the start at least) are meaningless.

You go =18, <=18, >=18

If the value is 18 the first two comparisons are ignored, you repeat the error for comparing with 10.

Without knowing exactly what you are wanting to do I would say they should be
=18, <18, >18

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace the "if score" statments with this code :

```
Select Case score
            Case 0
                MsgBox("you have scored 0 out of 10" & varname)
            Case 1
                MsgBox("you have scored 1 out of 10" & varname)
            Case 2
                MsgBox("you have scored 2 out of 10" & varname)
            Case 3
                MsgBox("you have scored 3 out of 10" & varname)
            Case 4
                MsgBox("you have scored 4 out of 10" & varname)
            Case 5
                MsgBox("you have scored 5 out of 10" & varname)
            Case 6
                MsgBox("you have scored 6 out of 10" & varname)
            Case 7
                MsgBox("you have scored 7 out of 10" & varname)
            Case 8
                MsgBox("you have scored 8 out of 10" & varname)
            Case 9
                MsgBox("you have scored 9 out of 10" & varname)
            Case 10
                MsgBox("you have scored 10 out of 10" & varname)
        End Select
```

Comment: You probably should do: 
MsgBox("You have scored " & score.ToString() & " out of 10"  & varname)